# Keyboard hiding EditText if Status bar is Translucent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, window-soft-input-mode

I have a layout :

[image]

And here is its XML

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mScroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/top_bar_title_height"
            android:weightSum="11"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_img"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from_txt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/min_padding"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/id_my_business_card"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/id_add_new_business_card"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/top_heading"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_add"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/white_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/camerasection_flipcamera"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_message_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_top_rounded"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/med_below_padding">

        <!--<ScrollView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->


        <!--<LinearLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_profile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_header_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_header_height"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/general_margin"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/chatcontacticon"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_firstname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_lastname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/last_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_company"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/company_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/address"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/phone_number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_office_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/office_number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_addemail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/email_address"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_url"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/add_url"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/del_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/sharp_green"
            android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

        <!--</ScrollView>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now when I open keyboard it overlaps with the bottom EditText

[image]

I am using following tag in menifest

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Additionally **If I don't use below in java it works fine**

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS ,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```

but I must have to use the above line in order to make status bar Translucent.
Overall the internet there are codes to achieve the desire behaviour but all with out `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS`.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure but can u try by removing stateHidden in manifest? and add adjustPan

Comment: adjustPan is moving the whole screen up. I want the orange portion to be on the same place while the white to move up.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**,

You are missing the following property:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in the root RelativeLayout of the fragment.xml layout (Or possibly on the activity layout, not sure since we don't have the full structure of your app)

Comment: But this will remove translucent of status bar

Comment: Okay, can you tried to remove stateHidden and use adjustPan for keyboard mode

Comment: adjustPan is moving the whole screen up. I want the orange portion to be on the same place while the white to move up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

I have chnaged the scrollview position. Will you try this once?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/top_bar_title_height"
            android:weightSum="11"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/back_img"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from_txt"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/min_padding"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/id_my_business_card"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="7"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/id_add_new_business_card"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/top_heading"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_add"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="13dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/white_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/camerasection_flipcamera"
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mScroller"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/edit_message_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_top_rounded"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/med_below_padding">

        <!--<ScrollView-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->


        <!--<LinearLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_profile"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/drawer_header_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/drawer_header_height"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/general_margin"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/chatcontacticon"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_firstname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/first_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_lastname"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/last_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_company"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/company_name"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_address"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/address"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                    android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                    android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/phone_number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_office_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/office_number"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_addemail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/email_address"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/min_padding"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/general_forty"
                android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/addbutton"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText_url"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@null"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:hint="@string/add_url"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/grey_line"
                android:textColorLink="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/normal_text"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/new_chat_header"
            />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/del_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/med_padding"
            android:background="@color/sharp_green"
            android:padding="@dimen/med_below_padding"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btn_text"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <!--</LinearLayout>-->

        <!--</ScrollView>-->
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tried and no luck.

Comment: I check with both. For adjustPan all layout was moving up and with adjustResize nothing happenes.

Comment: @SyedaZunairah I have updated my answer try that. I didn't set any property in manifest as well.

Comment: did you check the other answer? i can't use    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" as this will remove translucent of status bar